# How can I repair a damaged overhead door insulation panel?

Tags: garage-door, hole-repair

Kids put a hole in the garage door. It looks like styrofoam.

[image]

Comment: Is the pic showing the inside or outside of the door. If inside, I would cover the damage with some aluminium tape and forget it.  If outside, the panel will need to be replaced.

Comment: Warranty claim: durable goods are expectrd to be durable.

Comment: @Jasen, if a person wants interior impact protection they can pay for fully-enclosed panels. Most don't consider that expense worth it. That's a choice, not a product failing.

Answer (score 1):

**That's mostly cosmetic.** There's little need to repair the insulation, especially since overhead doors leak like sieves anyway. That bit of foam damage will have a negligible effect on energy consumption.

I'd consider asking your local installer or the manufacturer about a **new insulation panel**. Chances are it's plug-n-play and not too costly.

Otherwise, just remove the lumpy bits with a sharp knife and **lay some contact paper over it** to pretty it up and go on with life. It won't be the last time a kid dings your stuff, so don't sweat it. Be aware that this surface is probably vinyl, so you'll need a hearty adhesive to get it to stick. I wouldn't try it in cool temperatures.

Again, no need whatsoever for involved, expensive, and messy repairs.

Answer (score 0):

Spray foam it, then trim the expansion amount off and paint it to match the color

Comment: be sure to use water-based foam and water or alcohol based paint,  other solvents will attack EPS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fill with spray foam to within a couple mm of the surface (or trim away after it's cured).
2. Get some good stiff modeling clay, press a good sized lump of it against the surrounding vinyl to get a flat patterned surface on the clay.
3. Spread vinyl repair kit goop (you might be able to get away with acrylic or poly caulk) over the hole.
4. Get a piece of saran wrap and spray one side with cooking spray oil.  Press the oiled side against the goop.
5. Use your clay to imprint the pattern.
6. After the goop cures, remove the saran wrap.

Comment: Good grief. That's massive overkill at all levels.